# Orchard: Can't access admin panel

Tags: orchardcms

I can't access my Orchard admin panel when using `localhost:4321/admin`. It always redirects me to `localhost:4321/Users/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2fadmin`.

Comment: Have you actually logged in? ^_^

Comment: i cant login because the login page did not show up, it always redirects me to localhost:4321/Users/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2fadmin

Comment: /users/account/logon did it for me.  Thanks Hazza!

Comment: HTTPS connection is the problem. You should enable it first then start the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are not seeing the login box because of a theme override.

[siteurl]/Users/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2fadmin is the URL that you get when you try to go to [siteurl]/admin while you are not logged in. If you are not seeing a login box on that page, that means that the shape is not available, most likely because of an override to a Content.cshtml file that removed @Display(Model.Content).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is struggling with this, make sure that Forms Authentication is enabled on IIS. This solved it for me. I should have checked this first.

Answer (score 0):

Set-up a machine key like the release notes explain: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Setting-up-a-machine-key

Comment: hi thank you for the reply, but i still cant access the admin panel.

Comment: Then you have the wrong credentials. You can reset the admin password by following these instructions: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/04/28/recovering-the-admin-password-in-orchard.aspx